# ThreeJS cannot update object geometry correctly in onBeforeRender callback

Tags: three.js

I am playing with ThreeJS framework and want to create some extended classes based on core objects. Some of them require refreshing their material/geometry before each render.

To share a problem with you, I prepared a short code example. There is a class Test derived from THREE.Mesh object. In the example I want to make its size be fixed when zooming camera. I added a "update" method with a single parameter: camera zoom. In the given example there are two places where the method is called from two places: from render function (15th line) and from onBeforeRender callback (30th line). I am getting the expected behavior (square size is not changed when zooming) only when 15th line is uncommented (which is called before calling render function). Calling the method from onBeforeRender gives unpredictable result for me.

See the code example below.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

function updateCamera(camera, width, height) {
  const k = 0.5
  camera.left = -k * width
  camera.right = k * width
  camera.top = k * height
  camera.bottom = -k * height
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}

function render() {
  updateCamera(camera, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  //test.update(camera.zoom)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

const width = 10
const height = 10

class Test extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor() {
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height)
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000
    })
    super(geometry, material)
    this.onBeforeRender = function(renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group) {
      this.update(camera.zoom)
    }
  }
  
  update(zoom) {
    this.scale.x = width / zoom
    this.scale.y = height / zoom
  }
}


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  render()
})

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color("#FFFFFF")
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, 0, 0, 0, 1e-9, 2 * 1e+9)
camera.position.z = 1e+9

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.addEventListener("change", render)

const test = new Test()
scene.add(test)
render()

const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```

Can anyone please give me advice on this problem? Live example is [here](https://codepen.io/pau1yak/pen/KKbZYwX)

Comment: Try calling `this.updateWorldMatrix( false, false )` at the end of your update method. You may have other problems with your code.

Comment: @WestLangley this helped! but do you know what the nature of such behavior? Seems that onBeforeRender works already in the next frame but not before. Not sure if it was supposed to be like this by design.

Comment: The renderer updates the scene graph matrices for you when you call `render()`. You need to update the object matrix again because you changed the object's scale.

Comment: From your explanation it seems that `onBeforeRender` is called after the scene graph is updated. I thought using `onBeforeRender` is equivalent to calling method before `render()`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct. `onBeforeRender()` is called after the scene graph matrices are updated. You can update and "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WestLangley. Adding `this.updateWorldMatrix(false, false)` solved the issue. The reason why it didn't work is that three.js updates scene matrices before `onBeforeRender` callback called, so I have to update matrix of modified object manually.

Below is the working code.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

function updateCamera(camera, width, height) {
  const k = 0.5
  camera.left = -k * width
  camera.right = k * width
  camera.top = k * height
  camera.bottom = -k * height
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}

function render() {
  updateCamera(camera, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  //test.update(camera.zoom)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

const width = 10
const height = 10

class Test extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor() {
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height)
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000
    })
    super(geometry, material)
    this.onBeforeRender = function(renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group) {
      this.update(camera.zoom)
    }
  }
  
  update(zoom) {
    this.scale.x = width / zoom
    this.scale.y = height / zoom
    this.updateWorldMatrix(false, false)
  }
}


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  render()
})

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color("#FFFFFF")
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, 0, 0, 0, 1e-9, 2 * 1e+9)
camera.position.z = 1e+9

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.addEventListener("change", render)

const test = new Test()
scene.add(test)
render()

const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```